# How get token from auth facebook4j?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

i will write my problem in this message and put link by `exception` (#number),i trying create web application that will from library `facebook4j`, I want get information about user account facebook and post information on facebook, in my code i can get json information about user or friends, but i get problem from token, when i work long time i get exception #1.

I'm generated this param `setOAuthAccessToken()` in `graph api explorer` copy and it paste in `setOAuthAccessToken()`. **How right set and get token?**
**How create authentication in my web application via `facebook4j`?**

Exception #1

```
FacebookException{
    statusCode=400,
    errorType='OAuthException',
    errorMessage='Errorvalidatingaccesstoken: SessionhasexpiredonFriday,
    25-Sep-1511: 00: 00PDT.ThecurrenttimeisFriday,
    25-Sep-1513: 55: 17PDT.',
    errorCode=190,
    errorSubcode=463,
    version=2.3.0
}
```

This is my code:

```
private final String TOKEN_VALUE = "CAACEdEose0cBAN5JHf6qs85DCcqKndE3N9XxjnMye3m7G7Re4VpSCqn4IzWXXoYeQe3QlUOH0NGucIWJbqfZBpFoHTUZA60YcZCZBwd4kCWD4g1qwZCyxy1ihpoiVuxZCV1u9ydjnhZCkNOoSqiqPpkzDWPfAc8ZBEDFtCvW78gZCbkZChrzfsMxpA3LZC08pZA5HrqaOe1BnrU1PiZAHJz4ZAEm3M";

private FacebookFactory facebookFactory;
private Facebook facebook;
private ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder;
private Configuration configuration;

public ConfigurationBuilder getConfigurationBuilder(){
    configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAppId("746931638784611");
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAppSecret("07e2df67b4fe40e3f2051d79f40387c2");
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(token);
    configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
    configurationBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    return configurationBuilder;
}
public Configuration getConfiguration(){
    return getConfigurationBuilder().build();
}
public FacebookFactory getFacebookFactory(){
    return new FacebookFactory(getConfiguration());
}

@Override
public String getFriends() {
    facebook = getFacebookFactory().getInstance();
    try {
        ResponseList<Friend> friends = facebook.getFriends();
        return friends.toString();
    }catch (FacebookException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```